# int.TryParse failing with Console.ReadLine() in C#

Tags: c#, console-application, tryparse

If I try the following code in a simple console application:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
bool isString = int.TryParse(input, out myid);
```

I receive an error saying "the best overloaded method match for 'int.TryParse(string out int)' has some invalid arguments. I cannot work out why. Can anyone shed any light on this please?

Comment: 1) You didn't post the declaration of `myid`. Is it an `int`? 2) You only posted the first part of the error message. The second part tells you why the compiler rejected the existing overload. The C# compiler writers put a lot of effort into good compiler messages, **read them**.

Comment: Obviously `myid` is no int...

Comment: If this is all your code, you have three, not one compiler errors. Post all relevant ones, the most relevant one being _"The name 'myid' does not exist in the current context"_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `myid` as `int` before you pass it to `int.TryParse`

```
int myid;
string input = Console.ReadLine();
bool isString = int.TryParse(input, out myid);
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you really need more explanation for these two lill lines of code ?! ;)

```
    do Console.Write("My ID: ");
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int myid));
```