# Operator / cannot be applied to operands of string and double C#

Tags: c#, .net

Sorry I'm new to C# I believe I'm not converting my string to an int correctly. Any help

```
using System;

namespace planetage
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const double jupiterYears = 11.86;
            string userAge;

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age"); //Ask for users age
            Convert.ToInt32(userAge = Console.ReadLine()); //take users age

            double mercuryAge = userAge / jupiterYears; //error message shows for this line
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading an integer from user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443827/reading-an-integer-from-user-input) and [int.TryParse with Console.ReadLine() in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27858574/int-tryparse-failing-with-console-readline-in-c-sharp/51806772)

Answer (score 6):

This line:

```cs
Convert.ToInt32(userAge = Console.ReadLine());
```

- Reads a line of text
- Stored it in the `userAge` string variable
- Calls `Convert.ToInt32` with that text
- Ignores the result

Instead, you want:

```cs
int userAge = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

(And remove the earlier declaration of `userAge`. In general, it's a good idea to declare local variables at the point where their value is first known. Very occasionally that's not possible, e.g. if the value is assigned conditionally, but it's *usually* fine.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have your assignment in the wrong part. Try:

```
using System;

namespace planetage
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const double jupiterYears = 11.86;
            int userAge; // Change userAge to be an int

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age"); //Ask for users age
            userAge = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); //take users age

            double mercuryAge = userAge / jupiterYears; //error message shows for this line
        }
    }
}
```

So you assignment to the variable need to be the part we're assigning to.